# Undistorted image is of none type in cv2.undistort

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to remove distortion in Camera. I have calibrated the camera and am now trying to reduce distortion using cv2.undistort().
I have tried the following code:

```
enter code here
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import glob

mtx = np.loadtxt('CAMERA_MATRIX.txt')
dist = np.loadtxt('DISTORTION_COEFF.txt')
imgs = glob.glob('test_imgs/*.jpg')

for imagename in imgs:
    im = cv2.imread(imagename)
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    h, w = im.shape[:2]
    newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
    # undistort
    dst = cv2.undistort(im, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    # crop the image
    x,y,w,h = roi
    dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    dst = cv2.resize(dst,(900,900),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    #dst_res = cv2.resize(dst,(w,h),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    #imstack = np.hstack((im,dst))
    cv2.imshow('Undistortion',dst)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The following error occurs:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in resize, file /home/atul/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3496
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 20, in <module>
    dst = cv2.resize(dst,(900,900),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.error: /home/atul/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3496: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize`

How do I debug this?

Comment: What are the values for `x, y, w, h` from your ROI? And have you tried viewing `dst` prior to resizing to be sure you're getting the proper region before resizing?

Comment: In my DISTORT_COEFF.txt file, I have changed p1 and p2 to zero. Now this code works